# DOMPDF attachment 1kb

Tags: php, email, pdf, dompdf

I am sending pdf attachment using DOMPDF (I used to do this with TCPDF, but TCPDF doesnt support CSS)

I receive the email, but the email is 1kb and cannot be opened.

I approached the email sending in DOMPDF as I would in TCPDF. I have Googled but could not find anything helpful. Please assist me.

```
<?php
/* include autoloader */
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

/* reference the Dompdf namespace */
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

/* instantiate and use the dompdf class */
$dompdf = new Dompdf();




$html = ' HTML CONTENT';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);



/* Render the HTML as PDF */
$dompdf->render();

//define the receiver of the email
$to = 'toemail@example.com';
$subject = 'SUBJECT -';
$repEmail = 'reply@example.co.za';

$fileName = 'filename.pdf';
$fileatt = $dompdf->Output($fileName, 'E');
$attachment = chunk_split($fileatt);
$eol = PHP_EOL;
$separator = md5(time());

$headers = 'From: Identykidz <'.$repEmail.'>'.$eol;
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' .$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";

$message = "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
$message .= "Dear user.  \r\n\r\nPlease find attached profile .\r\n".$eol;

$message .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;

$message .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$fileName."\"".$eol; 
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$message .= $attachment.$eol;
$message .= "--".$separator."--";


// Send the email
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
header("Location:successpage.php");


}
else {

echo "There was an error sending the mail.";
}  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/* include autoloader */
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

/* reference the Dompdf namespace */
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

/* instantiate and use the dompdf class */
$dompdf = new Dompdf();




$html = ' HTML CONTENT';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);



/* Render the HTML as PDF */
$dompdf->render();

**$pdf = $dompdf->output();** 

//define the receiver of the email
$to = 'toemail@example.com';
$subject = 'SUBJECT -';
$repEmail = 'reply@example.co.za';

$fileName = 'filename.pdf';
$fileatt = $dompdf->Output($fileName, 'E');
$attachment = chunk_split($fileatt);
$eol = PHP_EOL;
$separator = md5(time());

$headers = 'From: Identykidz <'.$repEmail.'>'.$eol;
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' .$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";

$message = "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
$message .= "Dear user.  \r\n\r\nPlease find attached profile .\r\n".$eol;

$message .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;

$message .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$fileName."\"".$eol; 
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$message .= $attachment.$eol;
$message .= "--".$separator."--";


// Send the email
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
header("Location:successpage.php");


}
else {

echo "There was an error sending the mail.";
}  
?>
```